# shell script and database

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, scripting

i am retrieving course names from database using shell scripting. when there becomes space in course name e.g computer science, environmental sciences etc then the name is stored in two different instances of list, i.e before space and after space like "computer" in different instance and "science" in different instance of list, but i want to store it like "computer science" in the same instance of list, how do i overcome this problem

here is my code for retrieving course names

```
db_value=`mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_db -rN --execute
    "SELECT CourseName FROM applicant_result"`
z=1
for value in $db_value
  do
      echo "V,eligibility_$z=$value"
      let "z+=1"
  done
  echo "E,resume"
```

And the result i get  (note values of V,eligibility_2 and V,eligibility_3)

```
V,eligibility_1=chemistry
V,eligibility_2=computer                                       
V,eligibility_3=science
V,eligibility_4=mathematics
V,eligibility_5=physics
```

Answer (score 3):

```
z=1
mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_db -rN --execute "SELECT CourseName FROM applicant_result" | while read value
do 
    echo "V,eligibility_$z=$value"
    let "z+=1"
done
echo "E,resume"
```

Comment: what if i am retrieving data(database) from two or more columns like first column is CourseName and second is CourseEligibility then what would be syntax for variable $value

Comment: That's harder. You need to output in a parsable format like CSV, and set IFS to the column delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If that way doesn't work, then don't do it that way. `for ... in` splits on words rather than lines.

A possibly better solution is to use something more line aware:

```
mysql blah blah blah | awk '{
    n = n + 1;
    print "V,eligability_"n"=$0
} END { print "E,resume" }'
```

See the following tanscript for proof of concept:

```
pax> echo 'chemistry
...> computer science
...> mathematcis
...> physics
...> basket weaving' | awk '{
...>     n = n + 1;
...>     print "V,eligibility_"n"="$0
...> } END {print "E,resume"}'
V,eligibility_1=chemistry
V,eligibility_2=computer science
V,eligibility_3=mathematcis
V,eligibility_4=physics
V,eligibility_5=basket weaving
E,resume
```

Comment: what if i am retrieving data(database) from two or more columns like first column is CourseName and second is CourseEligibility then what would be syntax for variable $value

Comment: @shehzy, I'd suggest asking that as a different question since it more closely matches the way SO is meant to work. Asking questions in comment boxes doesn't give you much coverage of the SO people.

Comment: @shehzy, I modified my answer accordingly, but I have to second **paxdiablo**. Also consider that this kind of parsing not extremely robust.

Answer (score 0):

The key could be the IFS variable - Input Field Separator
This determine on which characters the input should be broke to parts.
So in your case you want to separate by new lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

db_value=`mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_db -rN -e "SELECT CourseName, CourseEligibility FROM applicant_result"`

oldIFS="$IFS" # save old to be able to restore it later
IFS="
";
z=1
for value in $db_value; do
  name=`echo $value | cut -f1`
  elig=`echo $value | cut -f2`
  #do whatever with $name and $elig
  echo "V,eligibility_$z=$name"
  : $[z++]
done
IFS="$oldIFS"
echo "E,resume"
```

Comment: what if i am retrieving data(database) from two or more columns like first column is CourseName and second is CourseEligibility then what would be syntax for variable $value